# How do I update the winners "Point" column using SUM in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum, sql-update

I have a tournament where there can be several winners and losers in the same round. How do I update the winners points with 10% of the total of losers points.

Here is an example:

EXAMPLE 1

Anne, Betty, Charlotte and Brian all start with 1000 points. They play one game whist, with Anne and Betty winning.

The winners (Anne and Betty) must have 1% of losers points.

The losers (Charlotte and Brian) have a total of 2000 points.

Therefore, 1% of losers points are 20 points.

It gives 10 points to each of the two winners (Anne and Betty).

The result after the game is

Anne: 1010 points Betty: 1010 points Charlotte: 990 points Brian: 990 points

EXAMPLE 2

In another game, Erik, Frederik, Gunnar and Helge play. For convenience, they also all start with 1000 points.

In this game, Erik gets to win while the other three lose.

So Erik must have 1% of the other players' points.

Frederik, Gunnar and Helge have a total of 3000 points.

1% of the losers' points is thus 30.

These 30 points must be added to Erik's total points, while each of the three losers must have deducted 10 points.

The result after the game is thus

Erik 1030 points
Frederick: 990 points
Gunnar: 990 points
Weekend: 990 points

I have tried something like this but the winners point is only updated with 10% of their own points

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE Players
SET Point = Point + 0.01 * (select distinct Point from Result where Winner = '0')
FROM Result
INNER JOIN Players ON Players.ID = Result.PlayerID
WHERE Winner = 1;

COMMIT TRAN;
```

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Players
(
    ID      INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,   
    Point   INT         NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Round
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Player1 INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Players(ID)  NOT NULL,
    Player2 INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Players (ID) NOT NULL,
    Player3 INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Players(ID)  NOT NULL,
    Player4 INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Players(ID)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Result
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    RoundID  INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Round(ID)   NOT NULL,
    PlayerID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Players(ID) NOT NULL,
    Winner BIT NOT NULL
);
    
  
  INSERT INTO Players (Name, Point)
  VALUES 
  ('Morten', 1000),
  ('Jens', 1000),
  ('Mie', 1000),
  ('Sanne', 1000);

INSERT INTO Round (Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4)
VALUES 
  ('1', '2', '3', '4');

INSERT INTO Result (RoundID, PlayerID, Winner)
VALUES 
  ('1', '1', '1'),
  ('1', '2', '1'),
  ('1', '3', '0'),
  ('1', '4', '0'),
  ('2', '1', '1'),
  ('2', '2', '0'),
  ('2', '3', '0'),
  ('2', '4', '0');
```

Comment: Does the winner need the points from **every** losing player in the table, or only those in the same round?

Comment: Adding more than 1 Round, with expected results will help us help you here, as we can then understand the full logic.

Comment: I have updated the question with two examples and  with data for an extra round.

Comment: YOur example don't tie up with yoru sample data though, making this not simple to replicate.

Comment: Is it better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the additional info about the calculation. You've made life a little harder then it needs to be with your table structure. This query takes a few steps to break it down first, but I think it does what you need:

```
WITH round_summary as
(
    SELECT 
        roundID
    ,   loss_points = sum(case when winner = 0 then point end)
    ,   count_winners = count(case when winner = 1 then playerID end)
    from
        Result
        join Players on Result.PlayerID = Players.ID
    group BY
        roundID
)

, round_unpvt as
(
    Select
        roundID = ID
    ,   playerID
    from
        [round]
        cross apply
        (   values
            ([Player1]) 
        ,   ([Player2]) 
        ,   ([Player3])
        ,   ([Player4])
        ) unpvt(playerID)
)

, points_calc as
(
    Select 
        round_unpvt.PlayerID
    ,   new_points = sum(0.1 * loss_points / count_winners)
    From
        round_unpvt
        join round_summary
            on round_unpvt.roundID = round_summary.roundID
        join result
            on result.roundID = round_unpvt.roundID
            and result.playerID = round_unpvt.playerID
    where
        winner = 1
    group by
        round_unpvt.PlayerID
)

UPDATE Players
SET [Point] = [Point] + new_points
FROM Players
INNER JOIN points_calc ON Players.ID = points_calc.PlayerID
```

Making the "Round" table more like a zipper table (four rows, one for each player, per round, instead of all on one row) would make this query simpler.

Comment: I had to edit the code little bit cause I could not use SUM on a BIT data type. wins = sum(CAST(winner AS INT)). Even though the code is executed correct the points are not updated in the Players table. It is very strange as I have not experienced this before. Any suggestions why the query is executed successfully but the points are not updated?

Comment: How many points should a person receive per win?
At the moment, your code is awarding 0.01 points for each win, and that is being rounded down to 0 when updating the INT value of points in the Players table.
Perhaps you meant to multiply by 100 instead? Or you need to change the Points column to be a decimal instead of an INT.

Comment: The winners get 1% of the losers total points. I have added examples in the question. The code you provided works perfectly. Thank you for that! I have now learned a couple things thanks to you  @James Mc. How would a deduction of points work? I have just added the following code at the end of your code and it works, but is there a smarter way of doing it?                                                                                                    
`UPDATE Players
SET Point = Point - (Point*0.01)
FROM Result
INNER JOIN Players
ON Players.ID = Result.PlayerID
WHERE Winner = 0`

Comment: Hi @Tamas - if the answer above solves your initial problem, please mark the answer as correct. This will help others in finding a correct solution for a similar problem, and save other people from trying to answer it.

Comment: Regarding deducting points, the query you have in the comment seems fine. Deductions are easier because you don't need to track where the points are going.
it would be good practice to perform a check after the two queries finish to ensure that the total amount of points across all players has remained the same. That you give you some confidence that both updates worked as expected.